# Save data instered (in the data table) using the R shiny package

Tags: r, web, architecture, shiny, shinydashboard

I am making an R shiny app (I am quite new to R shiny) which gets data as an input and projects the data as a table (using DT package). However when new data is inserted and submitted new rows are not being added, but rather the previous observation (previous submitted data is simply updated. Thus, what can I do to make save the new data data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem in your code was you were creating a new data frame and replacing it with the previous one. I have slightly modified your server code. I have added a global variable `TabData` to save the previous data in the data table and `rbind` it with the new data to be added to the table. Please see the modified code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(car)    # Import library to use recode() function

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  #Global variable to save the previous data in the data table
  TabData <- data.frame()

  values <- reactiveValues()
  # Calculate damage and loss (just ab experiment)
  observe({
    input$action_Calc
    values$int <- isolate({input$reduction * 10})

    values$amt <- isolate({input$lost}) + values$int

    values$com<-isolate({input$community})

    values$disaster <- isolate({input$disaster})

    values$name <- isolate({input$name})

  })

  # Display values entered
  output$text_principal <- renderText({
    input$action_Calc
    paste("reduction: ", isolate(input$reduction))
  })

  output$text_intrate <- renderText({
    input$action_Calc
    paste("Vegetation: ", isolate(input$veg))
  })

  output$text_int <- renderText({
    if(input$action_Calc == 0) ""
    else
      paste("Damage:", values$int)
  })

  output$text_amt <- renderText({
    if(input$action_Calc == 0) ""
    else 
      paste("Loss:", values$amt)
  })

  Data <- reactive({
    browser()
    if (input$action_Calc > 0) {
      df <- data.frame(
        Community= values$com,

        Disaster = values$disaster,

        Name = values$name,

        Damage=values$amt,

        Loss=values$int



      )
      return(list(df=df))
    }
  })



  output$responses <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
    if (is.null(Data())) {return()}
    #Row bind the new data to be added to the table
    TabData <<- rbind(TabData, Data()$df)
    datum<-TabData

    datum


  }))
})
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Dear @SBista, what does method browser() do when you call it? I didn't have it in my server ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I used that to debug your code and forgot to remove it before posting the answer. You can just remove that.